# Search for doorknob

Tags: doors, hardware

I want to replace this broken doorknob and just assumed it had a wrap-around plate until I took it off. Can anyone tell me the name for this style of doorknob so that I can find a replacement? [image]

Comment: I am _far_ from expert on this, but to me that looks like "home made, bodge job" brand, made to repair a damaged door. Nothing wrong with that if you have some metal working skills to do the metal, but not the woodworking skills to repair the door. A local wood/furniture restoration or architectural recycling place (that resells old doors, windows, etc.) would be able to repair the door - they might give you a quote on fixing the wood up if you were interested in that instead of the metal.

Answer (score 8):

There are [door reinforcement plates](https://www.acehardware.com/departments/hardware/door-hardware/door-guards/50672) that provide the same function. I can't tell from your picture if your door knob and reinforcing plate came bundled together.

[image: Door guard]

Comment: It does look sort of purpose built, but it doesn't matter; you're putting in a new lock with one of those plates, +1.

Comment: I'm not sure the ..  I don't know what to call them, slot-mortised? -- locks are still available except via places that specialize in parts removed from older buildings. A wrap-around of this sort may indeed be the best you can do unless you have the skills to recondition/repair the unit you have or are willing to take it to a locksmith and ask them what they would charge to get it back in operating condition. If all the parts are basically there and not too worn, and it just needs paint removed and new springs, that might be DIYable.

Answer (score 0):

A *notch* handle?

Kwikset Notch Hall 1.375 Inch Sliding Door Pocket Lock, Polished Brass (3 Pack)

[image]

https://www.walmart.com/ip/Kwikset-Notch-Hall-1-375-Inch-Sliding-Door-Pocket-Lock-Polished-Brass-3-Pack/175924723

Comment: For sliding pocket doors or closets.